# replace elements in string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I have a string **"Hello World !"** and I want to replace some letters in it and receive result like "**He!!! W!r!d !**"  it's means that i changed all **"l"** and **"o"** to **"!"**
I found function **preg_replace()**;

```
function replace($s){
    return preg_replace('/i/', '!', "$s");
}
```

and it works with exactly one letter or symbol, and I want to change 2 symbols to **"!"**.

Comment: Why not just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php?

Comment: Use an `array` with the `str_replace` then you can replace both characters.

Comment: I used that manual but it's works only with arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function as such;

```
function replace($s) {
    return preg_replace('/[ol]/', '!', $s);
}
```

Read more on regular expressions [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) to get further understanding on how to use regular expressions.

Comment: It's works. thank you! but it's also replace **","** to **"!"**.

Comment: @MichaelShtefanitsa, just remove the comma between "o" and "l".

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using regular expressions, why not *really* use then to work with the pattern you are *really* looking for?

```
preg_replace('/l+/', '!', "Hello"); // "He!o" ,so rewrites multiple occurances
```

If you want *exactly* two occurances:

```
preg_replace('/l{2}/', '!', "Helllo"); // "He!lo" ,so rewrites exactly two occurances
```

Or what about that:

```
preg_replace('/[lo]/', '!', "Hello"); // "He!!!" ,so rewrites a set of characters
```

Play around a little using an online tool for such: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_replace` like you did:

```
$s = 'Hello World';
echo preg_replace('/[lo]/', '!', $s);
```

I think another way to do it would be to use an `array` and `str_replace`:

```
$s = 'Hello World';
$to_replace = array('o', 'l');
echo str_replace($to_replace, '!', $s);
```

Comment: Why the comma in `[l,o]`?

Comment: It was a typo mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished either using `preg_replace()` like you're trying to do or with `str_replace()`

Using `preg_replace()`, you need to make use of the `|` (OR) meta-character

```
function replace($s){
  return preg_replace('/l|o/', '!', "$s");
}
```

To do it with `str_replace()` you pass all the letters that you want to replace in an array, and then the single replacing character as just a string (or, if you want to use multiple replacing characters, then also pass an array).

```
str_replace(array("l","o"), "!", $s);
```

[Live Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fb37669d383a3192540020581244db2a2e8ba9b)